# If not exist, append. If exist, increment count

Tags: python, regex, append

I am quite new to Python (well programming in general), and could really use your help.

I am trying to read through a firewall log file. I am interested in all lines with Deny in them. If found it should extract the source IP, destination IP, destination port and protocol. But I don't want to see all the lines, only unique ones. So far so good. Everything is working (albeit I am sure it could have been done much smarter) as such, but I also would like to add a counter so I can see how many times the specific combination of s_ip, d_ip, d_port and protocol has occurred, but I don't know how.

Example of log file:

```
Nov  9 00:36:10 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/43882 dst outside:2.2.2.2/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:10 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/38780 dst outside:2.2.2.2/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:11 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/8273 dst outside:2.2.2.2/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:12 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/23433 dst outside:2.2.2.22/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:12 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/25175 dst outside:2.2.2.24/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:12 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/15855 dst outside:2.2.2.26/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:12 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/24574 dst outside:2.2.2.27/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:12 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:1.1.1.1/21797 dst outside:2.2.2.29/23 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:12 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src outside:3.3.3.3/12112 dst outside:2.2.2.99/53031 by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:13 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny icmp src outside:4.4.4.4 dst services:2.2.2.211 (type 11, code 1) by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
Nov  9 00:36:17 firewall %ASA-4-106023: Deny icmp src outside:4.4.4.4 dst services:2.2.2.10 (type 3, code 3) by access-group "outside-in" [0x0, 0x0]
```

I am able to get the following result

```
'icmp'
'tcp', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '23'
'tcp', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.22', '23'
'tcp', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.24', '23'
'tcp', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.26', '23'
'tcp', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.27', '23'
'tcp', '1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.29', '23'
'udp', '3.3.3.3', '2.2.2.99', '53031'
```

I haven't quite managed to get the icmp output (icmp is without /port and my regex is using that to get the IP addresses), and I will try to make the output a little nicer (try to remove the ' and ,), but what I really would like is a hitcount on each line, e.g. the first tcp line would have a hitcount of 3 and so on.

```
import re       #for regular expressions - to match ip's
import sys      #for parsing command line opts

# if file is specified on command line, parse, else ask for file
if sys.argv[1:]:
    print "File: %s" % (sys.argv[1])
    logfile = sys.argv[1]
else:
    logfile = raw_input("Please enter a file to parse, e.g /var/log/secure: ")

match = []
seen = []

# find all Deny lines and append them in a list
for lines in open(logfile) :
    extract = re.findall('Deny.*"' ,lines)
    for i in extract :
        match.append(i)

# extract different keywords from Deny lines
for lines in match :
    prot = re.findall('Deny\s(.+?)\ssrc',lines)
    ip_src = re.findall('src.*?:([0-9a-f].*?)/', lines)
    ip_dst = re.findall('dst.*?:([0-9a-f].*?)/', lines)
    #ip_sport = re.findall('src.*?[0-9a-f].*?/([0-9].*?)\s', lines)     # uncomment if you want source port also, and add ip_sport to summarized below
    ip_dport = re.findall('dst.*?[0-9a-f].*?/([0-9].*?)\s', lines)

    summarized = prot + ip_src + ip_dst + ip_dport

    if summarized not in seen :             # only add unique entries
        seen.append(summarized)


# sort 
seen.sort()

for lines in seen :
    print ( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in lines ) )
```

Further more, I was trying to throw a 3GB log file at it, and it now has been running some hours. Any good ideas to optimize code?

I realize I am asking a lot of questions and any help is appreciated, but my primary question is help in getting counters on the lines.

Comment: SO is not a code review/teaching service. You should ask specific programming question. Please, restrict yourself to asking a single problem per post.

Comment: On the other hand, [codereview.se] _is_ a code review / teaching service. You don't need to have a specific programming question — just some working code that you need advice on.

Comment: duly noted :o). Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python standard library already has a [`Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

You could change the `seen` variable to be a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

[...]

seen = Counter()

# extract different keywords from Deny lines
for lines in match :

    [...]

    summarized = prot + ip_src + ip_dst + ip_dport

    # NOTE: summarized must be a string or tuple.
    seen.update([summarized])
```

At the end, the `seen` dictionary will have each unique summarized line as keys and the count for each line will be the value.

Regarding the optimization, it'd be better (i think) if you process each line as you encounter it, in the `for lines in open(logfile)` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much - I have implemented your suggestions in regards to counters and they worked like a charm :o)

Comment: If this worked for you, please show your appreciation by marking this as your accepted answer. If you need more help, then post a separate question. I've rolled back your question from Rev 2 to Rev 1.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeating entries you could use a `set` instead of a `list`. I would do:

```
seen = set()
for lines in open(logfile) :
    extract = re.findall('Deny.*"' ,lines)
    for i in extract :
        prot = re.findall('Deny\s(.+?)\ssrc',i)
        ip_src = re.findall('src.*?:([0-9a-f].*?)/', i)
        ip_dst = re.findall('dst.*?:([0-9a-f].*?)/', i)
        #ip_sport = re.findall('src.*?[0-9a-f].*?/([0-9].*?)\s', i)
        ip_dport = re.findall('dst.*?[0-9a-f].*?/([0-9].*?)\s', i)
        seen.add((prot, ip_src, ip_dst, ip_dport)) #Add here ip_sport if you want
```

This should be faster as it uses less loops, on the other hand `set`s are unordered (Here's is a recipe to build it though, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/). If you don't want to build it and order you should convert it to a list before printing